# Can I access an a copy of bash profile current terminal is running right now?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I've mistakenly deleted the ~/.bashrc,
but I have a running terminal with all the settings.
Is it possible to access contents of ~/.bashrc as it was at the time of starting the terminal?

Comment: I suggest to save output of `alias` and `set` to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot, however, you can recover the settings, and use them to recreate your `~/.bashrc`. Use:

```
(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >some.file
```

Then starting with a copy of `/etc/skel/.bashrc`, and `some.file`, you can recreate,

BTW, You probably meant "mistakenly deleted", not "accidentally deleted".

Comment: Thanks, `alias` is what I needed. There was some important script for my networking setup.